# Having a hard time tracking down all linux dependencies for Qt based app

Tags: linux, qt

I have my app working on OSX and Win, but am having a hard time tracking down all of the required dependencies for Linux. Ideally I'd like to be able to run it on Fedora, CentOS and possibly Ubuntu. Ubuntu is lower priority however.

Will someone help me figure this out? I can get my way around Linux decently well but am not a pro. This has me quite stumped.

http://www.genecrucean.com/tmp/KickAssGUI.tar.gz (It's a simple GUI app for a 3D renderer called Arnold. www.solidangle.com)

Comment: How in the heck does this NOT relate to programming? I guess it's code only and good luck for anything after compile? This is absolutely and directly related to programming in Qt.

Answer (score 5):

Currently your tarball contains the binary .so files for Qt 5. This is usually not the way to do it on Linux. You can either provide the source code of your program and let the users build it for themselves, or you can kindly provide a pre-built package (.rpm or .deb) for the Linux distribution in question. This means building packages specifically for a certain release of Fedora, again for CentOS, and again for Ubuntu. These packages would depend on libqt5, a package provided by the Linux distribution itself.
For finding out more dependancies, use ldd:

```
$ ldd program
```

Running the same compiled binary across different Linuxes is usually a no-no because of differences in the versions of the underlying shared libraries, although some companies do it, namely for commercial games.
If you use static linking then it can work. Until they change something big in the kernel.

You should also take the target architecture into consideration: ia32, amd64, or maybe something else.

Maybe this question is better answered at ServerFault.

Comment: +1 for the package distribution and being brave enough to download random files.  However, the part about the same shared libraries version is only partially correct.  If the major versions are the same and the minor version of the compiled source is less than the run-time, then things are ok.  Also, the kernel developers strive to maintain compatibility; you have to rely on some esoteric things for this to break a program.  More likely is the distributions change their kernel `.config`.